# Linux - list all subdirectories and get ACL

Tags: linux, acl, ls

I am trying to:

1. List all the subdirectories under a top level directory (/shared) and output this to a file called directory_list
2. Afterwards I want to run getfacl using the file as input, and output the results to a file called acl_list

So ultimately, getting the ACLs for all subdirectories in /shared.

The steps I'm trying to use are:

1. `ls -d -- /shared/*/*/*/ > directory_list`
2. `getfacl < directory_list > acl_list`

Is there a different command I can use for (1) where it will list the subdirectories recursively, as -dr (list directories recursively) does not seem to work. Also I do not know how many levels of subdirectories there are.

When I run the 2nd command, there seems to be some syntax error preventing it from running, but I've checked the syntax from the linux man pages and it should be right.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: `getfacl` expects the names to be arguments, it doesn't get them from stdin. You can use `xargs` to convert stdin to arguments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use `find` to do a recursive list:

   ```
   find /shared -type d -print > directory_list
   ```
2. `getfacl` expects the filenames to be command line arguments, it doesn't read standard input. Use `xargs` to perform this translation:

   ```
   xargs -d '\n' getfacl < directory_list > acl_list
   ```

The `-d` option specifies the delimiter, overriding the default use of whitespace. However, I believe this is a GNU extension, it may not be in all versions of `xargs`. If you can't use it, you'll have to write a loop:

```
while read -r filename; do 
    getfacl "$filename"
done < directory_list > acl_list
```

Comment: Thanks - that works except that the "xargs getfacl" can't handle spaces in the directory names. Do you know how this can be rectified?

Comment: Added the `-d` option.

Answer (score 1):

I know you actually asked for this, but do you technically speaking NEED the intermediate directory_list ?

```
find /shared -type d -print -exec getfacl "{}" \+ > acl_list
```

Comment: Thanks this one is perfect and let me choose to get all from the root directory :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `find` command should get you what you need:

```
find /shared -type d
```

`-type d` restricts the output to directories only.

Comment: I don't think `-ls` normally shows ACLs, it just shows traditional permission modes.